# Need to get averages of from yesterday, and that same day of the week, for 3 weeks back

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script to collect the totals from yesterday's sales, which runs every morning and gives the managers totals by hour.

Here's the main part:

```
$yesterday = 1
[datetime]$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$yesterday).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
[datetime]$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$yesterday).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$excelStartDate = $startDate.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]
$excelEndDate = $endDate.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]
$fileDateYesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$yesterday)



    $sql1 = "

    USE STORESQL
        
            SELECT FORMAT(TRS.F254, 'MM-d-yyyy') AS 'Date',
                   'Time' = CASE 
                        WHEN TRS.F01 = 06 THEN '6 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 07 THEN '7 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 08 THEN '8 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 09 THEN '9 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 10 THEN '10 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 11 THEN '11 AM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 12 THEN '12 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 13 THEN '1 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 14 THEN '2 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 15 THEN '3 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 16 THEN '4 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 17 THEN '5 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 18 THEN '6 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 19 THEN '7 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 20 THEN '8 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 21 THEN '9 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 22 THEN '10 PM'
                         WHEN TRS.F01 = 23 THEN '11 PM'
                   END,
                   SUM(TRS.F65) AS 'Total Sales',      
                   SUM(TRS.F64) AS 'Transactions',
                   (round(SUM(TRS.F65)/SUM(TRS.F64), 2)) AS 'Avg Basket Size'
        
            FROM RPT_HOU AS TRS 
                    JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
                    JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 and TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057

            WHERE TRS.F1031= 'D' AND 
                    TRS.F254 BETWEEN '$startDate' and '$endDate' AND
                    TRS.F1034 BETWEEN '2' and '2' AND
                    TRS.F01 BETWEEN '06' and '22' AND
                    LNK.F1000 NOT IN ('DSM', 'PAL', 'RAL', 'XAL')

            GROUP BY TRS.F254, TRS.F01
            ORDER BY TRS.F254

    "
```

Outputs this:

[Transactions by Hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d58Nm.png)

Now they want the averages by hour for yesterdays, going back three weeks. If yesterday was a Monday, they want the averages of the last 3 Mondays.

I was attempting to throw AVGs in the select with some hard coded dates for testing, but that wasn't working. Now I'm wondering if this query should be re-written completely to accomplish this. :(

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I would turn you existing code into a function where the Date is an input.  Add the DayOfWeek as a column  You can then create a view for each Day where you can then join the views to get averages.

Comment: Could you give me a small code example of how I'd make the current code into a function and use it? The rest I'll should be able to piece together through testing. Thank you!

Comment: Use Create Function .  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/function-operation-in-sql-database/

Comment: A couple of comments, you have TRS.F01 BETWEEN '06' and '22' but your case when also checks hour 23, bug? I'd also probably create view if you have a lot of static WHERE conditions. Finally, to get average, i'd probably use a correlated subquery that fetches yesterday +  7 and 14 days back and average them together